# ASP.NET mvc View with IEnumerable model and input tag helper

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In this [official ASP.NET Core tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-views), I can use an [Input Tag Helper](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/working-with-forms.html#the-input-tag-helper) as shown below. But due to a [known model binding issue of form elements in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636604/1232087), I want to use `for loop` instead. **Question**: If I were to replace `@foreach (var item in Model)` with `@for (int i=0; i < Model.Count(); i++)` in the following `View`. What would be my `asp-for` in `<input asp-for="???" />` ? For some reason, intellisense is not recognizing, e.g, Model[i].BlogId or @Model[i].BlogId

```
@model IEnumerable<EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models.Blog>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blogs";
}

<h2>Blogs</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-controller="Blogs" asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Url</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@item.BlogId" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@item.Url" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you need input form fields if they are not in a form ? If it is only for display purpose, you can simply print the value.

Comment: @Shyju This post is only for the purpose of explaining my question. In real project, I do need input form fields and I do want to experiment input tag helper with `for loop` because of the problem with foreach loop (as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636604/1232087)). Also, @model need to be IEnumerable.

Comment: You cannot use a `for` loop with `IEnumerable<T>` - it would need to be `IList<T>`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Translations.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Translations[i].LanguageId)
    <form-group-text asp-for="@Model.Translations[i].Content"/>
}
```

The important part is using the `for` loop, and accessing the `asp-for` via `@Model`.

That said, you should rethink, if your Model itself should be `IEnumerable`. Instead create a property for it. Also you need to make sure, your Collection is accessable via Index. You could make your property of type `IList`. When you assign an `IEnumerable` to it, you can call `ToList` before.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @model IEnumerable<EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models.Blog>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Blogs";
    }

    <h2>Blogs</h2>

    <p>
        <a asp-controller="Blogs" asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Url</th>
        </tr>
    @for (int item = 0; item < Model.Count(); item++)
        {
           <tr>
              <td>
                <input name="@Model.ToList()[item].BlogId" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input name="@Model.ToList()[item].Url" />
              </td>
          </tr>
       }
    </table>
```