# Dynamic forms in ASP .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, entity

I have Property table, it has Id and Name.

I need to dynamically write a form for those properties.

I tried something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Properties) {
                                <div class="col-md-6 margin_top_15">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => item.Name, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Name, new {@class = "form-control"})
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
}
```

Problem is I'm getting form like this:

[image]

I'm understand why this is happening, because Property name is always same name - "Name".

Model is:

```
public class PropertyField {
        [Key]
        public int FieldId { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

I can change LabelFor to Label and get good look of field, but on submit model is null:

```
@Html.Label(item.FieldName, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `foreach` loop to standard `for` loop instead, because generating same element ID for multiple elements will produce invalid markup:

```
// assumed that Model.Properties has type of List<PropertyField>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-6 margin_top_15">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Properties[i].FieldName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Properties[i].FieldName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Properties[i].FieldName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

By using `foreach` loop, MVC default model binder can't binding all properties in view page correctly because certain HTML elements have incorrect naming, hence the list collection contains null value after submitting the form.

Related issue:

[For each loop with controls and submitting form (Html.BeginForm) in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636284/for-each-loop-with-controls-and-submitting-form-html-beginform-in-mvc-4)